# SQL query counting the number of results where different conditions hold

Tags: sql, sql-server, conditional-statements

I have a query that looks like

```
SELECT ju.name,
    COUNT(DISTINCT p.value) AS nproblems
FROM #problems p
JOIN <thing> ju ON <whatever>
WHERE <condition 1>
    AND <condition 2>
    AND <condition 3>
GROUP BY ju.name
ORDER BY nproblems DESC
```

This is fine, and gives me a result set with names and values. But what I really care about is the number of problems without the WHERE clause, then with just condition 1, then conditions 1+2, then conditions 1+2+3. I'd like to write

```
SELECT ju.name,
    COUNT(DISTINCT p.value WHERE <condition 1>) foo,
    COUNT(DISTINCT p.value WHERE <condition 2>) bar,
...
```

but sadly I can't. Is there a nice way of doing this?

Comment: +1 nice question: as Mahmoud suggested - try using `CASE` in the `SELECT` clause and get rid of the `WHERE`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `CASE` expression to do so:

```
SELECT ju.name,
    SUM(CASE WHEN <condition 1> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS foo,
    SUM(CASE WHEN <condition 1> THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS bar,
    ...
FROM #problems p
JOIN <thing> ju ON <whatever>
GROUP BY ju.name
ORDER BY nproblems DESC;
```

**However:** If you are using a RDBMS that supports the `PIVOT` table operator like MS SQL Server or Oracle, you can use it to do so, directly.

---

Since you are using SQL Server, you can use the [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) table operator to do so:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
) AS t
PIVOT
(
   COUNT(value)
   FOR name IN(...)
) AS p;
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I'm indeed using MS SQL server -- not sure I see what I'd pivot. Could you give an example?

Comment: @katrielalex - It depends, I post just a simple pseudo code of how to do so, but there are other variations. Can you please post some sample data from the two tables with the desired output? it will be helpful.